# How do I interpret `flatpak install` output?

Tags: command-line, output, flatpak

I'm simply trying to install Spotify with `flatpak install spotify`. Here's the output:

```
Looking for matches…
Found similar ref(s) for ‘spotify’ in remote ‘flathub’ (system).
Use this remote? [Y/n]: y
Found ref ‘app/com.spotify.Client/i386/stable’ in remote ‘flathub’ (system).
Use this ref? [Y/n]: y
Required runtime for com.spotify.Client/i386/stable (runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/i386/18.08) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [Y/n]: y

com.spotify.Client permissions:
    ipc                    network                pulseaudio               x11            dri
    file access [1]        dbus access [2]        bus ownership [3]        tags [4]

    [1] xdg-music:ro, xdg-pictures:ro
    [2] org.freedesktop.Notifications, org.gnome.SessionManager, org.gnome.SettingsDaemon
    [3] org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify
    [4] proprietary


        ID                                             Gren           Op         Remote          Hämta
 1. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale                18.08          i          flathub            25,6 kB / 316,0 MB
 2. [—] org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel           18.08          u          flathub             1,9 MB / 1,9 MB
 3. [ ] org.freedesktop.Platform.html5-codecs          18.08          u          flathub           < 3,4 MB
 4. [ ] org.freedesktop.Platform                       18.08          i          flathub         < 306,7 MB
 5. [ ] com.spotify.Client                             stable         i          flathub         < 109,0 MB
```

A list of obscure permissions -- fine, but after that? A numbered list of IDs? Op `i/u`? I don't know what it's trying to say. It's going to perform `u`ninstall operations..? At least the permission section had a heading.

I looked at the reference documentation for `flatpak install` but found no description of the output.

Also, after accepting the above without knowing what it meant the install process is constantly interrupted and requiring me to authenticate, forcing me to stay and watch over the whole process. Why does it ask me to authenticate over and over instead of just once? I just aborted the process after 3+ authentications since I don't feel like babysitting this thing...

---

Ubuntu MATE 18.4 32 bit

Comment: @guiverc "Running third-party applications on Ubuntu" There you go. Added distribution info at the bottom.